# Backbone collection sortBy

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I make my first backbone app and get some problems with collection sorting. 
After using this

```
var SortedFriends = MyFriends.sortBy(function(friend) {
          return friend.get("uid");
        });
```

console.log(SortedFriends) show that SortedFriends contains sorted models, but when i try to use collection functions like 'SortedFriends.each' or 'SortedFriends.at' it make error:

TypeError: SortedFriends.each is not a function.

Code:

```
  var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({});          
      var Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Friend,            
      });  

      var MyFriends = new Friends();
      MyFriends.reset(<?=$friends?>);

      var FriendView = Backbone.View.extend({
          initialize: function(){
              model:Friend            
          },              
          tagName: "tr",
          template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),
          className: "document-row",          
          render: function() {                              

         this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));                            
              return this;             
          }          
      });     


    var SortedFriends = MyFriends.sortBy(function(friend) {
      return friend.get("uid");
    });          

    var addOne = function(element){           
        var view = new FriendView({model: element});
        $("#friends").append(view.render().el);
    }                              
    console.log(JSON.stringify(SortedFriends));
    SortedFriends.each(function(friend){
        var view = new FriendView({model: friend});
        $("#friends").append(view.render().el);            
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

If youre using backbone collections then youre probably better off using the `comparator` rather than collection methods

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator

When youre ready to sort your collection:

```
MyFriends.comparator = function(friend){
   return friend.get("uid");
});
MyFriends.sort();
```

OR if you want to keep the order of the unsorted collection then you will need to clone it first

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-clone

```
var SortedFriends = MyFriends.clone();
SortedFriends.comparator = function(friend){
   return friend.get("uid");
});
SortedFriends.sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's a bug or a feature of Backbone's adaptation of `sortBy`, but apparently it returns an array, not an Underscore collection.

One workaround is to wrap the whole thing in `_( ... )`, which tells Underscore to wrap the array back into a collection:

```
var SortedFriends = _(MyFriends.sortBy(function(friend) {
  return friend.get("uid");
}));
```

**Edit**

Most of the Underscore methods in Backbone seem to be chainable (replace `sortBy` with `reject`, for example, and it runs).  Looking at the Backbone source where they wire up the Underscore proxies, it seems that `sortBy` is treated differently.  I can't understand why they do it this way ...

```
var methods = ['forEach', 'each', 'map', 'collect', 'reduce', 'foldl',
    'inject', 'reduceRight', 'foldr', 'find', 'detect', 'filter', 'select',
    'reject', 'every', 'all', 'some', 'any', 'include', 'contains', 'invoke',
    'max', 'min', 'toArray', 'size', 'first', 'head', 'take', 'initial', 'rest',
    'tail', 'drop', 'last', 'without', 'indexOf', 'shuffle', 'lastIndexOf',
    'isEmpty', 'chain'];

_.each(methods, function(method) {
    Collection.prototype[method] = function() {
      var args = slice.call(arguments);
      args.unshift(this.models);
      return _[method].apply(_, args);
    };
});

var attributeMethods = ['groupBy', 'countBy', 'sortBy'];

_.each(attributeMethods, function(method) {
    Collection.prototype[method] = function(value, context) {
      var iterator = _.isFunction(value) ? value : function(model) {
        return model.get(value);
      };
      return _[method](this.models, iterator, context);
};
```

Comment: This help

var SortedFriends = _(MyFriends.sortBy(function(friend) {
  return friend.get("uid");
}));

Thank you!