# Weird behavior in using sortBy with Backbone/Coffeescript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using Backbone with Coffeescript. The code I use for my view is:

```
    initialize: ->
      @collection.on "reset", @render, @
      @collection.fetch({reset: true})

    render: ->
      @collection = @collection.sortBy (item) -> item.get('name')
      @collection.forEach @renderEntry, @
      @

    renderEntry: (model) ->
      v = new App.Views.EntryView({model: model})
      @$el.append(v.render().el)
```

The problem is when I want to sort Backbone collection on the first line of *render function* I get **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'sortBy'** error. If I change render function and rewrite it as :

```
    render: ->
      sorted = @collection.sortBy (item) -> item.get('name')
      sorted.forEach @renderEntry, @
      @
```

then everything works fine. What's wrong with original code?

I tried to move sorting functionality to another function and nothing changed. Again when I want to assign sorted collection to the collection itself I get the same error.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sortBy returns an array back and not the actual collection. Therefore sorted is an array and not a Backbone.Collection. I am guessing you are trying to resort on an Array as oppose to the collection itself. So your @collection will throw an error when you try resort, because it is no longer a Backbone.Collection. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010714/backbone-collection-sortby)

Comment: The problem is not the collection. If I try to assign the result of sortBy to the collection itself I get the error but if I assign the result to another variable like sorted as mentioned before everything works and JS does not throw runtime error. Actually problem occurs on the right part of "=" sign and when I change the left side everything goes fine. quite puzzled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem is that **reset** event gets triggered two times. One by Backbone and second time by fetch. So the first time that I call

```
    @collection = @collection.sortBy (item) -> item.get('name')
```

it replaces the collection with empty array (since nothing is fetched yet), hence there is no sortBy method in it to be called in the next run.

Replacing the line with:

```
  (@collection = @collection.sortBy (item) -> item.get('name')) if @collection.length > 0
```

solves the issue.